# How to batch queries and perform them later in pyneo2 v3?

Tags: py2neo

In py2neo V2, it was possible to do this by using query.append() which add the query to a queue and all the queries can be executed later.

How can I do the same thing in v3? I cannot find an equivalent function in the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is in Python 3.6.3 using `py2neo` version 3.1.2:

`from py2neo import Graph
g = Graph(host="localhost", user="neo4j", bolt=True)  # Modify for your situation
transaction = g.begin(autocommit=False)
transaction.append("match(n) return count(n);")`

This fails and returns the following warning:

`/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: Transaction.append(...) is deprecated, use Transaction.run(...) instead`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As far as I understand run will send the query to the server for processing and append used to add it to a queue of queries. You would later use transaction.process() to send all the queries to the server for processing. So perhaps there is no way to queue queries and then execute them altogether?

Comment: @jyotsnasingh yes there is. Take a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75842/optimizing-for-data-import-in-neo4j-using-py2neo) post where he batches into 1000

Comment: Yeah, but here he again uses batch.append() which does not work for version 3

Comment: @jyotsnasingh the error I posted in my answer gives you exactly what to do. Verbatim: `use Transaction.run(...) instead`